# Covering for binary naturals as a higher inductive type

Tags: agda, cubical-type-theory

An answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61439685/cubical-agda-how-do-i-prove-two-things-not-equal) noted that given an inductive type in Cubical Agda (v2.6.1, Cubical repo version `acabbd9`), one should proceed to define a relation on the datatype by recursion and then prove that this relation is equivalent to path equality; this allows "encode/decode" or "NoConfusion" proofs which let you prove equalities more easily.

So I have the following definition of the binary naturals as a higher inductive type: essentially, a binary natural is "a list of bits, little-endian, but adding most-significant zeros doesn't change the number". (I thought this seemed the most natural definition, but I can't actually find a similar definition anywhere already.)

```
{-# OPTIONS --safe --warning=error --cubical --without-K #-}

open import Agda.Primitive
open import Cubical.Core.Everything
open import Cubical.Foundations.Prelude

module BinNat where

data False : Set where
record True : Set where

data List {a : _} (A : Set a) : Set a where
  [] : List A
  _::_ : A → List A → List A

_++_ : {a : _} {A : Set a} → List A → List A → List A
[] ++ y = y
(x :: xs) ++ y = x :: (xs ++ y)

data Bit : Set where
  z : Bit
  o : Bit

data BinNat : Set where
  bits : List Bit → BinNat
  addZeros : (x : List Bit) → bits (x ++ (z :: [])) ≡ bits x
```

Now, the obvious relation was the following, which identifies two lists of bits if they are the same or if one differs from the other only in the number of zeros on the most-significant end:

```
CoverBitList : List Bit → List Bit → Set
CoverBitList [] [] = True
CoverBitList [] (o :: b) = False
CoverBitList [] (z :: b) = CoverBitList [] b
CoverBitList (z :: xs) [] = CoverBitList xs []
CoverBitList (o :: xs) [] = False
CoverBitList (z :: xs) (z :: ys) = CoverBitList xs ys
CoverBitList (z :: xs) (o :: ys) = False
CoverBitList (o :: xs) (z :: ys) = False
CoverBitList (o :: xs) (o :: ys) = CoverBitList xs ys

Cover : BinNat → BinNat → Set
Cover (bits x) (bits y) = CoverBitList x y
Cover (bits x) (addZeros y i) = ?
Cover (addZeros x i) (bits y) = ?
Cover (addZeros x i) (addZeros y j) = ?
```

I just about fought my way through filling the first two holes, proving along the way `coverBitListWellDefinedRight : (x y : List Bit) → CoverBitList x (y ++ (z :: [])) ≡ CoverBitList x y` and `coverBitListSym : (x y : List Bit) → CoverBitList x y ≡ CoverBitList y x`.

But the final hole looks… ghastly. I don't have the intuition to reason about paths between paths yet.

Is there a teachable chunk of intuition I'm missing that will help me fill that hole, and/or is there an easier way to fill the hole, and/or am I doing the right thing at all in defining this `Cover` type?

Comment: Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141417/defining-non-unary-functions-in-cubical-mode links to https://github.com/gergoerdi/cubical-playground/blob/916696414436377f501d2b15d3edb06c22b0c996/Int.agda which I think may be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I got it!

The trick was to define everything super explicitly so that Agda could reduce everything very eagerly for me.

```
coverBitListWellDefinedRight : (x y : List Bit) → CoverBitList x (y ++ (z :: [])) ≡ CoverBitList x y
coverBitListWellDefinedRight [] [] = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedRight [] (z :: y) = coverBitListWellDefinedRight [] y
coverBitListWellDefinedRight [] (o :: y) = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedRight (z :: as) [] = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedRight (o :: as) [] = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedRight (z :: as) (z :: y) = coverBitListWellDefinedRight as y
coverBitListWellDefinedRight (z :: as) (o :: y) = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedRight (o :: as) (z :: y) = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedRight (o :: as) (o :: y) = coverBitListWellDefinedRight as y

coverBitListWellDefinedLeft : (x y : List Bit) → CoverBitList (x ++ (z :: [])) y ≡ CoverBitList x y
coverBitListWellDefinedLeft [] [] = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedLeft [] (z :: y) = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedLeft [] (o :: y) = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedLeft (z :: xs) [] = coverBitListWellDefinedLeft xs []
coverBitListWellDefinedLeft (o :: xs) [] = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedLeft (z :: xs) (z :: ys) = coverBitListWellDefinedLeft xs ys
coverBitListWellDefinedLeft (z :: xs) (o :: ys) = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedLeft (o :: xs) (z :: ys) = refl
coverBitListWellDefinedLeft (o :: xs) (o :: ys) = coverBitListWellDefinedLeft xs ys

Cover : BinNat → BinNat → Set
Cover (bits x) (bits y) = CoverBitList x y
Cover (bits x) (addZeros y i) = coverBitListWellDefinedRight x y i
Cover (addZeros x i) (bits y) = coverBitListWellDefinedLeft x y i
Cover (addZeros [] i) (addZeros [] j) = True
Cover (addZeros [] i) (addZeros (z :: []) j) = True
Cover (addZeros [] i) (addZeros (z :: (z :: y)) j) = Cover (addZeros [] i) (addZeros (z :: y) j)
Cover (addZeros [] i) (addZeros (z :: (o :: y)) j) = False
Cover (addZeros [] i) (addZeros (o :: y) j) = False
Cover (addZeros (z :: []) i) (addZeros [] j) = True
Cover (addZeros (z :: (z :: xs)) i) (addZeros [] j) = Cover (addZeros (z :: xs) i) (addZeros [] j)
Cover (addZeros (z :: (o :: xs)) i) (addZeros [] j) = False
Cover (addZeros (o :: xs) i) (addZeros [] j) = False
Cover (addZeros (z :: []) i) (addZeros (z :: ys) j) = Cover (addZeros [] i) (addZeros ys j)
Cover (addZeros (z :: (z :: xs)) i) (addZeros (z :: ys) j) = Cover (addZeros (z :: xs) i) (addZeros ys j)
Cover (addZeros (z :: (o :: xs)) i) (addZeros (z :: ys) j) = Cover (addZeros (o :: xs) i) (addZeros ys j)
Cover (addZeros (z :: []) i) (addZeros (o :: ys) j) = False
Cover (addZeros (z :: (z :: xs)) i) (addZeros (o :: ys) j) = False
Cover (addZeros (z :: (o :: xs)) i) (addZeros (o :: ys) j) = False
Cover (addZeros (o :: xs) i) (addZeros (z :: ys) j) = False
Cover (addZeros (o :: xs) i) (addZeros (o :: ys) j) = Cover (addZeros xs i) (addZeros ys j)
```